# Change docker storage engine from devicemapper to overlay2

Tags: docker, backup

I have 3 running containers in production. I have to move storage strategy to overlay2. I've committed my containers and I've saved these committed images as `tar` file.

Now I'm getting ready to remove all old docker stuff and then I'll change storage strategy.

Did anybody do this critical operation? Any suggestions to be in safe zone?

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE:** You will lose access to all your current images and containers due to layers! Reverting your changes will make your old images and containers accessible again. You can use `docker save IMAGE:TAG > IMAGE.tar.gz` to save your current images and `docker load < IMAGE.tar.gz` to import them on the new storage driver.

Follow these steps:

*Stop docker:*

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
```

*Edit the file /etc/docker/daemon.json (create it if doesn’t exist) and add the following to the file:*

```
  {
  "storage-driver": "overlay2"
  }
```

Start docker:

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

Use docker info to verify that the storage driver is being used:

```
  $ docker info
  ...
  Storage Driver: overlay2
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt to implement it obtained this:

```
failed to start daemon: error initializing graphdriver: overlay2: the backing xfs filesystem is formatted without d_type support, which leads to incorrect behavior. Reformat the filesystem with ftype=1 to enable d_type support.
```

In my case, that was my root filesystem; I created a new filesystem and symlinked /var/lib/docker to the new mount after having copied the contents and done

```
sudo semanage fcontext -a -e /var/lib/docker /vm0/docker
```

While it didn't directly touch the volume contents, all record of the how the running containers were to be configured was lost, e.g., networking, port maps, etc.  An attempt to recreate one of the containers using its docker-compose file re-downloaded the public images, which then proceeded to corrupt its until then intact volume.

In another instance, I imported a saved image and had memorialized its invocation in a shell script wrapping "docker run ...." - but that failed with

```
docker: Error response from daemon: No command specified.
```

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#prerequisites